# &SECT; display as small black square html instead of §

Tags: html

sometimes § encode character display as small black square bracket but in inspect window it display as section symbol §.
Please find attached screen shot.[image]

In my MVC web application, I am using kendo grid to display reports. Reports contains the paragraph text which may contains special characters. when I look into grid, it display this character as black square but when export to excel, it display as section character.
can any one suggest the reason for this?

Comment: “font-family: Wingdings”

Comment: Change font family